# This version of Xcode doesnt support Auto Layout for IOS Documents

Tags: ios, storyboard

I was using Xcode 4.5 Beta 3 when creating a program. When I tried to switch to Xcode 4.4 it gives me the following error. How do I get it to work in this version of xcode.

```
The document "MainStoryboard.storyboard" could not be opened. This version of Xcode does not 
support Auto Layout for iOS documents.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the project in 4.5 and figure out how to turn off auto layout and turn "springs and struts" on. I don't have this release now, but had a similar issue with OSX. In my case I could select an xib file, then in the 3rd pane on file attributes I could change it.

Answer (score 5):

Open the project in 4.5 and figure out to turn off 'Use Autolayout' in Interface Builder Document of File Inspector.
And save project.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install XCode 4.5 for some reason, you can right click on the offending .xib, select Open As/Source Code, and then search for `Autolayout`. In my case, this attribute was at the very end of the file. Change the `YES` to `NO` and you will be able to build your project. I had to take this route because XCode 4.4.1 was refusing to have anything to do with the .xib files saved by Xcode 4.5.